# HDP 3.0 sandbox hive with spark configuration

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am new to using HDP Sandbox, and looking to change execution engine for Hive to use as Spark rather than default Tez.

I followed below URL to configure Hive Warehouse connector

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_configure_a_spark_hive_connection.html

and

changed the configuration hive.execution.engine=spark in $HIVE_HOME/hive-site.xml. When I look at the job status it shows submitted query with "Application Type" as Tez. How can I configure hive to execute using spark engine?

Comment: can you try setting the same config in the hive shell directly using set property and try , instead of changing in hive-site.xml

Comment: I will try and let you know.